# Grok Syntax Issues

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm using filebeat to send log to logstash but I'm having issues with grok syntax on Logstash. I used the grok debugger on Kibanna and manager to come to a solution.
The problem is that I can't find the same syntax for Logstash.

The original log:

```bash
{"log":"188.188.188.188 - tgaro [22/Aug/2022:11:37:54 +0200] \"PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/xxx@yyyy.com/ HTTP/1.1\" 207 1035 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows) mirall/2.6.1stable-Win64 (build 20191105) (Nextcloud)\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-08-22T09:37:54.782377901Z"}
```

The message receive in Logstash:

```bash
"message" => "{\"log\":\"188.188.188.188 - tgaro [22/Aug/2022:11:37:54 +0200] \\\"PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/xxx@yyyy.com/ HTTP/1.1\\\" 207 1035 \\\"-\\\" \\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows) mirall/2.6.1stable-Win64 (build 20191105) (Nextcloud)\\\"\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2022-08-22T09:37:54.782377901Z\"}",
```

The Grok Pattern I used on Grok Debugger (Kibana):

```bash
{\\"log\\":\\"%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \\\\\\"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\\\\\\" (?:-|%{NUMBER:response}) (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes}) \\\\\\("%{DATA:referrer}\\\\\\") \\\\\\"%{DATA:user-agent}\\\\\\"
```

The real problem is that I can't even manage to get the IP (188.188.188.188).
I tried:

```bash
match => { "message" => '{\\"log\\":\\"%{IPORHOST:clientip}' # backslash to escape the backslash
match => { "message" => '{\\\"log\\\":\\\"%{IPORHOST:clientip}' # backslash to escape the quote
match => { "message" => "{\\\"log\\\":\\\"%{IPORHOST:clientip}" # backslash to escape the quote
```

The log used here is shrink. The real log is mixed with JSON and string so I can't send it as JSON in Filebeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i manage to make it work by using this :

```bash
     grok {
                match => { "message" => '%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:syslog_server} %{WORD:syslog_tag}: %{GREEDYDATA:jsonMessage}' }
        }
     json {
                source => "jsonMessage"
        }
     grok {
                match => { "jsonMessage" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \\"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\\" (?:-|%{NUMBER:response}) (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes}) \\("%{DATA:referrer}\\") \\"%{DATA:user-agent}\\"'}
                
        }
```

with log like this :

```bash
Aug 24 00:00:01 hostname containers: {"log":"188.188.188.188 - user.name@things.com [23/Aug/2022:23:59:52 +0200] \"PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/ HTTP/1.1\" 207 1159 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.4.2-1ubuntu1 (Nextcloud, ubuntu-5.15.0-46-generic ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-08-23T21:59:52.612843092Z"}
```

The first match will fetch the first 3 field (time, hostname and tag), and then get everything after the `:` with the pattern `GREEDYDATA` in the jsonMessage.
Than the json filter is used on the jsonMessage. Since then, we have the information needed in the new field log created by using the json filter.

I still don't understand why my grok work on Kibanna debugger but not on Logstash. I mean it's probably because some character needs to be escaped. But even when i escape them it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You has already filtered out the JSON using the **JSON Filter** and trying to match the `jsonMessage` using the **GROK Filter**

I used the [GROK Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to create a grok pattern that will match `jsonMessage` field.

The `jsonMessage` that I assumed coming after using the JSON Filter for the above log example is:

`188.188.188.188 - user.name@things.com [23/Aug/2022:23:59:52 +0200] \\"PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/ HTTP/1.1\\" 207 1159 \\"-\\" \\"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/3.4.2-1ubuntu1 (Nextcloud, ubuntu-5.15.0-46-generic ClientArchitecture: x86_64 OsArchitecture: x86_64)\\"\\n"`

Here is pattern that will work:

`%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{DATA:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \\\\"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) \\\\"`

[image]

Output Screenshot:

[image]

> Note: If you want to expand the `rawrequest` field value into individual filed, it can be done also.